# How can I spontaneously print a loop in function python

Tags: python, physics

so i am doing a computational physics homework, i need to make a calculator to calculate a range of number from 1 to 10 which is time (t) to my function. My code looks like this

```
import numpy as np
def vonx(v,theta):
    
        theta_to_radian = np.deg2rad(theta)
        vx = v*np.cos(theta_to_radian)*time

 
        return vx
```

so how do i spontaniously calculate this equation including time and have multiple answer?

also, can I use input to input the value of v and theta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming that you want to print the values of vx dynamically for time from 0 to 10:

```
import numpy as np

v = int(input())
theta = int(input())

def vonx(v,theta, time):
    
        theta_to_radian = np.deg2rad(theta)
        vx = v*np.cos(theta_to_radian)*time
 
        return vx

for time in range(11):
    print(vonx(v,theta,time))
```

Comment: @divyeesh how do i plot it into a graphic?

Comment: you are free to use libraries like matplotlib or seaborn

Comment: they are quite easy to use